# What is the best way to give support `nth-child` in one shot to all IE version?

Tags: javascript, css

What is the best way to give support `nth-child` in one shot to all IE version?

I want to give style like this. for some particular pages.

```
#products tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}


#products tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Define "all". IE8 and IE7 seem obvious. IE6, IE5, IE1? What does "all" mean?

Comment: hehe...I doubt he means IE1. I'm assuming ie6-ie9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That project](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) gives you "native" support for these and many others CSS3 selectors for at least IE7/8.

But here you'll have a problem with IE7 which doesn't support `background-color` for `tr`.

Comment: i need only support for nth child. don't need other selectors

Comment: Would it be wise to use whole library just for one selector?

Comment: IMHO yes. That's a huge facilitation for now, and for future. Oh.. and the best is that you don't have to change any code. Just attach that JS code and "magically" your code works! ;)

Comment: @metal: You'll almost certainly find that you need to support another missing feature in IE, so better to already have a library that fixes everything before it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in javascript.

```
var table = document.getElementById('products');

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
{
   if ( (i % 2) == 0 )
   {
       rows[i].className = 'even';
   }
}
```

then do your CSS like this:

```
#products tr td
{
    background-color: white;
}

#products tr.even td
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you have used a javascript library, you could have done this :

```
$('#products tr:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 1):

I made something that should work in every browser:
https://gist.github.com/yckart/5652296

```
var nthChild = function (elem, num) {
    var len = elem.length;
    var ret = [];

    // :nth-child(num)
    if (!isNaN(Number(num))) {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i === num - 1) return elem[i];
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(numn+num)
    if (num.indexOf("+") > 0) {
        var parts = num.match(/\w/g);
        for (var i = parts[2] - 1; i < len; i += parts[0] << 0) {
            if (elem[i]) ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(odd)
    if (num === "odd") {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(even)
    if (num === "even") {
        for (var i = 1; i < len; i += 2) {
            ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
};


var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var num = nthChild(rows, 2);
var formula = nthChild(rows, "3n+1");
var even = nthChild(rows, "even");
var odd = nthChild(rows, "odd");


// Note, forEach needs to be polyfilled for oldIE
even.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += " even";
});

odd.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += " odd";
});

formula.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += " formula";
});

num.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery too, and they'll likely have solved your cross browser issue.

```
$('#products').children('tr:even').css('background-color', 'red');
$('#products').children('tr:odd').css('background-color', 'white');
```